# Combining assoc arrays for report in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i'm trying to make a report by combining two arrays.

My first array :

```
echo json_encode($arr_default);
[
    {"01":"0"},{"01":"0"},{"01":"0"},{"01":"0"},{"01":"0"}
    ,{"02":"0"},{"02":"0"},{"02":"0"},{"02":"0"},{"02":"0"}
    ,{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"}
    ,{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"}
    ,{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"}
    ,{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"}
    ,{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"}
    ,{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"}
    ,{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"}
    ,{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"}
    ,{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"}
    ,{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"}
]
```

My second array :

```
echo json_encode($arr_data);
//[
    {"01":"11.600"},{"01":"0"},{"01":"0"},{"01":"11.600"},{"01":"11.600"}
    ,{"02":"6.133"},{"02":"6.133"},{"02":"0"},{"02":"0"},{"02":"6.133"}
    ,{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"14.667"}
]
```

This is my code so far, but the result is not right:

```
$arr_final = array();
foreach($arr_default as $dt_arr_default)
{
    $found=false;
    foreach($arr_data as $dt_arr_data)
        {
            if(key($dt_arr_default)==key($dt_arr_data))
            {
                $arr_final[] = $dt_arr_data;

                $found=true;
                break;
            }
    }
            if(!$found)
            { $arr_final[]=$dt_arr_data; }  
}
```

My code result:

```
[
    {"01":"11.6"},{"01":"11.6"},{"01":"11.6"},{"01":"11.6"},{"01":"11.6"}
    ,{"02":"6.1"},{"02":"6.1"},{"02":"6.1"},{"02":"6.1"},{"02":"6.1"}
    ,{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"}
    ,{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"}
    ,{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"}
    ,{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"}
    ,{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"}
    ,{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"}
    ,{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"}
    ,{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"}
    ,{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"}
    ,{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"}
]
```

The result I want :

```
[
    {"01":"11.6"},{"01":"0"},{"01":"0"},{"01":"11.6"},{"01":"11.6"}
    ,"02":"6.1"},"02":"6.1"},{"02":"0"},{"02":"0"},{"02":"6.133"},    
    {"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"0"},{"03":"14.6"}
    ,{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"},{"04":"0"}
    ,{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"},{"05":"0"}
    ,{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"},{"06":"0"}
    ,{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"},{"07":"0"}
    ,{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"},{"08":"0"}
    ,{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"},{"09":"0"}
    ,{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"},{"10":"0"}
    ,{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"},{"11":"0"}
    ,{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"},{"12":"0"}
]
```

and lastly how can I foreach the array to be like this:

```
01   11.6   0     0   11.6   11.6
02    6.1   6.1   0    0      6.1
03    0     0     0    0     14.6
04    0     0     0    0      0
05    0     0     0    0      0
06    0     0     0    0      0
07    0     0     0    0      0
08    0     0     0    0      0
09    0     0     0    0      0
10    0     0     0    0      0
11    0     0     0    0      0
12    0     0     0    0      0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: _How_ do you want combine your arrays?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the two objects? Merge with duplicates, without duplicates, merge and combine into arrays with unique keys? Combine and sort them in order? Add more description of what you exactly want. Or if you want to get creative and try yourself, take a look at the Lo-dash or Underscore libraries: https://lodash.com/docs.

Comment: @federico any method is fine. but i prefer the simpler one. Most importantly matching the result i want.

Comment: @show-me-the-code I want to merge the arrays. not erase the duplicate

Comment: totally missed the php tag and was suggesting JS solution. my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert that array in a format more easy to use.

```
// Only if you are using php < 5.5
if(!function_exists("array_column")) {
    function array_column($array, $column_name) {
        return array_map(function ($e) use ($column_name) { return $e[$column_name]; }, array_filter($array, function($item) use ($column_name) {
            return isset($item[$column_name]);
        }));
    }
}

$keys = [];
foreach ($first_array as $data) {
    $keys[] = key($data);
};

$results = array_fill_keys($keys, array());
array_walk($results, function(&$item, $key) use ($first_array, $second_array) {
    $item = array_replace(array_column($first_array, $key), array_column($second_array, $key));
});
```

You can use `$results` to iterate over arrays, like this:

```
foreach ($results as $name => $result) {
    echo $name, '    ', implode('    ', $result), "\n";
}
```

And for recreating the result in the format you want,

```
$newResults = [];
foreach ($results as $name => $result) {
    foreach ($result as $data) {
        $newResults[][$name] = $data;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/I2Z7k).

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column()

Comment: I edit with a workaround, I see if there is a cleaner solution

Comment: @ashura91, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you organize your first array like this

```
$arr_default = array(
     "01"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"02"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"03"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"04"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"05"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"06"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"07"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"08"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"09"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"10"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"11"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
    ,"12"=>array("0","0","0","0","0")
);
```

And the second like this

```
$arr_data = array(
    "01"=> array("11.600","0","0","11.600","11.600")
    "02"=>,array("6.133","6.133","0","0","6.133")
    "03"=>,array("0","0","0","0","14.667")
);
```

You can take advantage of the similar keys:

```
foreach($arr_data as $key=>$replaceWith) {
    $arr_default[$key] = $replaceWith;
}
```

Then to print that array you simply

```
foreach($arr_default as $key=>$arr) {
    echo $key . "\t" . implode("\t",$arr);
}
```

Where you'd change the \t to whatever you want. So to build an actual HTML table:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($arr_default as $key=>$arr) {
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>" . $key . "</td><td>" . implode("</td><td>",$arr) ."</td>
    </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

To convert your current arrays to this multi-dimensional format:

```
$new_arr_data = array();
foreach($arr_data as $pai) {
    list($key,$value) = $pair;

    $new_arr_data[$key][] = $value;
}
$arr_data = $new_arr_data;
```